# Open in MudPopover does not work for global static bool values

Tags: blazor, mudblazor, mudpopover

I want to build a set of popovers with Severity(Info, Success, etc), Icons, Colors, Open or not. To Simplify and synchronize the parameters, I want to set only the Severity. Meanwhile Icons, colors are generated by the severity, and Open is controlled by a set of global switches.

I have a sandbox in the end, and it works. But final code here does not work. The popover does not toggle when the switch is on or off.

In one word: The Open works with a [Paramerter] or local static bool, not work in static bool somewhere else (which sounds really strange).

Any help? Thanks.

Code of pages contains popovers (default value of Servirity is Info):

```
        <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="@UiGlobal.DisplayPopoverInfo" Color="Color.Primary" Label="Info" />
        <AiBadge Text="Text"></AiBadge> @*Does not toggle*@
        <AiBadge Open=@(@UiGlobal.DisplayPopoverInfo) Text="Text"></AiBadge> @*Can toggle*@
        <AiBadge Open="@UiGlobal.DisplayPopover(Severity.Info)" Text="Text"></AiBadge>" @*Can toggle*@
```

Code in AiBadge component:

```
<MudBadge Icon="@Icon" Origin="@Origin" Color="@Color"
          Overlap="true" Elevation="4" BadgeClass="ml-4">
    <MudPopover OverflowBehavior="OverflowBehavior.FlipAlways" Open="@Open"
                AnchorOrigin="@Origin.CenterLeft" TransformOrigin="@Origin.CenterLeft" 
                Class="d-flex ml-8" Elevation="1">
        <MudAlert Severity="@Severity">
            @Text
        </MudAlert>
    </MudPopover>
</MudBadge>


@code {
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public Severity Severity { get; set; } = Severity.Info;
    [Parameter] public Origin Origin { get; set; } = Origin.CenterRight;
    public string Icon =>
            Severity == Severity.Success ? Icons.Material.Filled.CheckCircle
            : Severity == Severity.Warning ? Icons.Material.Filled.Warning
            : Severity == Severity.Error ? Icons.Material.Filled.Error
            : Icons.Material.Filled.Info;
    public Color Color =>
            Severity == Severity.Success ? Color.Success
            : Severity == Severity.Warning ? Color.Warning
            : Severity == Severity.Error ? Color.Error
            : Color.Info;

    //Can toggle with this parameter
    [Parameter] public bool Open{ get; set; } = true;
    // Does not toggle with this get only property
    // public bool Open =>
    //         Severity == Severity.Success ? UiGlobal.DisplayPopoverSuccess
    //         : Severity == Severity.Warning ? UiGlobal.DisplayPopoverWarning
    //         : Severity == Severity.Error ? UiGlobal.DisplayPopoverError
    //         : UiGlobal.DisplayPopoverInfo;
}
```

Code of UiGlobal here:

```
public static class UiGlobal
{
    public static bool NavMenuOpen { get; set; } = true;

    public static void OpenNavMenu() => NavMenuOpen = true;
    public static void CloseNavMenu() => NavMenuOpen = false;
    public static void ToggleNavMenu() => NavMenuOpen = !NavMenuOpen;

    public static bool DisplayPopoverInfo { get; set; } = true;
    public static bool DisplayPopoverSuccess { get; set; } = true;
    public static bool DisplayPopoverWarning { get; set; } = true;
    public static bool DisplayPopoverError { get; set; } = true;

    public static bool DisplayPopover (Severity severity) =>
            severity == Severity.Success ? UiGlobal.DisplayPopoverSuccess
            : severity == Severity.Warning ? UiGlobal.DisplayPopoverWarning
            : severity == Severity.Error ? UiGlobal.DisplayPopoverError
            : UiGlobal.DisplayPopoverInfo;
}
```

Official document here: https://www.mudblazor.com/components/popover#simple-popover

The sandbox works well here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QawHaVcPuVyeNDDn.